# Filtering a sum of reciprocal of integers

Tags: analysis

Let $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers. Moreover, let $A(x)$ be the set of positive integers $n$ such that $a_n \le x$, and fix a subset $B \subseteq \lim_{x\to \infty}A(x)$ such that 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{B(x)}{A(x)}=\frac{1}{2},
$$
where $B(x):=B\cap [1,x]$. Also, suppose that there exists a function $f(x)$, which does not converge, such that 
$$
\sum_{a_n \in A(x)}{\frac{1}{a_n}} \sim f(x), \text{ as }x\to \infty.
$$
Then, prove that
$$
\sum_{a_n \in B(x)}{\frac{1}{a_n}} \sim \frac{f(x)}{2}, \text{ as }x\to \infty.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If for some $x$, the sum is $>(1+\epsilon)\frac{f(x)}{2}$, then (per the decreasing of $\frac1{a_n}$) $A$ must contain "unusually many" early elements. For $x$ large enough this is not possible, because $A$ contains approximately half the elements of $[1,\frac x2]$